# Button not clickable once exiting the iFrame

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to automate a payment using selenium java via a modal. I am able to enter the CC details however when I exit the iframe to click the pay button nothing happens and I get an error in the console.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="chakra-modal--body-656"]/button"}
```

My Code is :

```
    //enter CC details
    driver.switchTo().frame(4);
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name='cardnumber']")).sendKeys(CCNUM);
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name='exp-date']")).sendKeys(expiry);
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name='cvc']")).sendKeys(cvc);
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name='postal']")).sendKeys(zip);
    System.out.println("cc details entered");
    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
    System.out.println("default content");
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    
    // Click purchase button
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"chakra-modal--body-684\"]/button")).click();

    Thread.sleep(2000);
    driver.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure following points:

- xpath("//*[@id="chakra-modal--body-684"]/button") belongs in default content.
- xpath("//*[@id="chakra-modal--body-684"]/button") does not belong in same frame(4) or another frame.